# MYSQL php: query multiple rows and return value if "WHERE IN" id not found

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am developing a website on wordpress that manages events.

The issue is that I need to get some event title names from their corresponding IDs in a single query. I am trying to get multiple rows out of a single MYSQL query, which works fine using "`WHERE IN ({$IDs})`":

```
$events_implode = implode(',',$events);
$events_titles = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `title` FROM `wp_events` WHERE `id` in ({$events_implode}) ORDER BY FIELD(id,{$events_implode}",ARRAY_A);
```

However, I need it to return a value/string if one of the $IDs was not found in the query instead of returning nothing.

Example:
If `$events_implode` is like: `318,185,180,377`, and the events with IDs 180 & 185 do not exist (being deleted for instance), I get back the events titles for 318 & 377 only:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 4
        )

)
```

while I need it to return something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 4
        )

)
```

I tried IFNULL:

```
$events_titles = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT IFNULL( (SELECT `title` FROM `wp_events` WHERE `id` in ({$events_implode}) ORDER BY FIELD(id,{$events_implode}) ),'not found')",ARRAY_A);
```

but since the query returns more than one row, I get the error message:

```
"mysqli_query(): (21000/1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row"
```

Is there a solution to that?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this by also querying the id and not just the title:

```
SELECT id, title FROM ... etc
```

Then your result array will look like this (for the example data)

```
array(
    0 => array("id" => 318, "title" => "title for 318"),
    1 => array("id" => 377, "title" => "title for 377")
)
```

But this can be converted to what you need, with the help of the *$events* array you already have:

```
foreach($event_titles as $row) {
    $hash[array_search($row['id'], $events)] = $row['title'];
};

$events_titles = $hash;
```

Now the array looks like this (for the example data):

```
array(
    0 => array("title" => "title for 318"),
    3 => array("title" => "title for 377")
)
```

NB: That conversion can also be done without explicit loop:

```
$ids = array_intersect($events, array_column($event_titles, 'id'));
$event_titles = array_combine(array_keys($ids), array_column($event_titles, 'title'));
```

#### Alternative

The above is probably the best solution for your case, but you could also build your query dynamically to achieve this:

```
$subsql = implode(
    ' UNION ALL ', 
    array_map(function ($event) { return "SELECT $event AS id"; }, $events)
); 

$sql = "SELECT    wp_events.title 
        FROM      ($subsql) AS eid
        LEFT JOIN wp_events ON wp_events.id = eid.id
        ORDER BY  eid.id";

$events_titles = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);
```

The value for *$subsql* will be like this (for example data):

```
SELECT 318 AS id UNION ALL
SELECT 185 AS id UNION ALL
SELECT 180 AS id UNION ALL
SELECT 377 AS id
```

The value of *$events_titles* will be an array that has one entry for each event, whether or not it matched. So for the example you gave, you would get this result:

```
array(
    0 => array("title" => "title for 318"),
    1 => array("title" => null), // because no match with 185
    2 => array("title" => null), // because no match with 180
    3 => array("title" => "title for 377")
)
```

So you can now just test for `null`. If additionally you would like to remove the `null` entries *without* changing the indexes (0 ... 3) in the array, then do this:

```
$event_titles = array_filter($event_titles, function ($title) { return $title; });
```

This will give you (in the example):

```
array(
    0 => array("title" => "title for 318"),
    3 => array("title" => "title for 377")
)
```

Comment: Using ids and events array didn't cross my thought...Great answer, totally solved my problem...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using in clause seems no possible but you can build a dinamic query using union form dual

```
"SELECT  t.index, a.`title` 
 FROM `wp_events` as a 
 INNER JOIN ( select  1 as index , 318 as id
             from dual 
             union 
             select 2, 185
             from dual
             union 
             select 3, 180
             from dual
             union 
             select 4, 377
             from dual                 

             ) t  on t.id = b.id
ORDER BY t.index"
```

Comment: I stil need to learn dynamic queries ...Your answer encourages me to do so..Thanks!

Comment: Well i hope that my answer is at least useful .. and for that you think to rate the  answer as useful

Comment: Kinda new to posting in stack overflow...sorry!
It's definitely useful...Thanks again (-:

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way. The returning array from the mysql-query has nothing to do with the implode-array you gave to the query. There might be options to achieve that (creating a temp-table, fill it with keys, left join from that table to the events-table), but please don't to that as it is bad practice and nut KISS (keep it simple, stupid).

The simple question is, why do you want to do that?

Comment: I map the events_titles array to another that carries event IDs and create buttons with id attributes that correspond to the event titles....If they don't match in index, the user would push one button and get a totally different result...
There are a few workarounds to avoid doing this, but solving this issue saved me time and extra programming steps.